# How to paste text into the descrpition field on Shopify by using Python Selenium

Tags: python, html, selenium-webdriver, shopify, webdriverwait

I wanna create a bot by using Python Selenium, which be able to paste value I gave for it. Headings and to select item - clear to me, but I don't know, how to paste text in description. For example:

[image]

So how I can paste text? I can't paste text in textarea and body element(XPath similar to main html and body)

```
description = browser.find_element(By.ID, 'product-description')
description.send_keys('fddfdfdfdf')
```

Answer (score 0):

As per the snapshot provided:

[image: frame]

the desired element is clearly with an an [`<iframe>`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53276478/7429447).

---

### Solution

To send a *character sequence* within the desired element you have to:

- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for the desired *frame to be available and switch to it*.
- Induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52607451/7429447) for the desired *element to be clickable*.
- You can use either of the following [locator strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver):

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR,"iframe_css_selector")))
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "product-description"))).send_keys("fddfdfdfdf")
  ```

Comment: Still not working :(
It doesn't even give an obvious error:
Message: 
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:

Comment: @kantemyr Did you replace `iframe_css_selector` with the actual real time value?

Comment: Yes, I did this: 
WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "#product-description_ifr")))
        WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "product-description"))).send_keys("fddfdfdfdf")